# Is it appropriate to speak of a "pre-study intern"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I completed a short internship at a large company before starting my studies in a similar field. This is often mandatory for engineering classes in Germany and called a "Vorpraktikum", literally translated a "pre-study internship".

I wonder whether it is appropriate to call the position "Pre-study Intern" in my CV, this would be in line with later internships (e.g. "Research Intern"), but sounds a bit odd to me.

How does this sound to a native speaker, do you have better suggestions?

Comment: I think "pre-study internship" or "pre-university internship" sounds fine. To an older generation, it might be called "work experience" but "intern/internship" seem much more commonly used. In the UK a year out before university is often called a "gap year" but this doesn't seem to be a common term in the US: so it might help to say what country you are aiming at.

Answer (score 1):

### Work experience / work placement

In the British-English speaking world, what you did is known as “work experience” or alternatively, “work placement”.

- **[work experience](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/work-experience)** *(noun, Brit.)*: a period of time in which a student temporarily works for an employer to get experience.
- **[work placement](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/work-placement)** *(noun, Brit.)*: a limited period of time, usually forming part of a course of study, during which someone works for a company or organization in order to get work experience, which may be paid or not paid.

(“work experience” is an uncountable nouns; you *do not* say “I did a work experience”, but “work placement” can be used as a countable noun to describe the posting itself)

Unlike the British-English use of “intern”, “work experience” does not automatically imply that you were in college or studying for that career: both secondary-school and undergraduate students can both do work experience. Work experience tends to be shorter duration, and can be paid or unpaid.  “Work *placement*”, by contrast, is longer in duration, usually part of a third-level qualification, and more likely to be as part of a third-level education, and more likely to be paid work.

I natively speak a British English dialect, not American, but my understanding is that in American usage, “intern” *does* cover pre-college work as well. Perhaps someone better-placed to know could comment?

Comment: Yes I'd be interested in the American English interpretation/word. The position was indeed paid due to German minimum wage laws.

Comment: @Lawrence - good point. I have edited my answer.